# Android Facebook User email not coming

Tags: android, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

When i was trying to get facebook email, some facebook users email coming and some facebook users email not coming.

Here is my code:

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "email","publish_stream" };

public void loginAndPostToWall() {
        facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                new LoginDialogListener());
    }

String responseData = facebook.request("me");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/#fields

> `email`: This person's primary email address listed on their profile. **This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.**